# rangy undoToRange remove span, even if attributes have changed

Tags: javascript, rangy

I am using rangy class applier.
https://github.com/timdown/rangy

`applyToRange` creates a span, and the `undoToRange` removes it as expected.

however, if I modify one of the attributes of the span, then `undoToRange` does not remove the span (it does remove the class though). How to remove the span using rangy (instead of a custom solution)?

```css
.myclass {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world</h1>
<button onclick="apply()">apply</button>
<button onclick="undo()">undo</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.0/rangy-core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangy/1.3.0/rangy-classapplier.js"></script>

<script>
node = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]

rangy.init();

rangyOptions = {
  elementAttributes: { 'data-name': 'hello'},
  useExistingElements: false,
};
applier = rangy.createClassApplier("myclass", rangyOptions);
var range = rangy.createRange();
range.selectNode(node);

function apply() {
  applier.applyToRange(range);
  // if a comment this, then undoToRange does remove the span.
  node.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].dataset.name = "world";
}

function undo() {
  applier.undoToRange(range);
}

</script>
```